# NSURL with Curly Braces

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurl

NSURL does not support the use of curly braces (i.e. {}) in URLs.  My application needs to talk to a server that requires the use of curly braces in the URL.  I'm considering using bridges to write the networking code in Python or C++, or even rewriting the C code for NSURL to make it accept curly braces.  Percent escapes are not accepted by my remote server.

Do I have any other good alternatives?

EDIT: Explained why addingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding and the like don't work for me here.

Comment: You may want to update your question title to NSURL with braces - I think you're presuming you need an alternative ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will it work for you if you escape the braces?

**This code:**

```
// escape {} with %7B and %7D
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com/%7B7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D%7D.htm"];
NSLog(@"%@", url);

// {} don't work and return null
NSURL *badurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com/{7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D}.htm"];
NSLog(@"%@", badurl);
```

**Outputs:**

```
2011-11-30 21:25:06.655 Craplet[48922:707] http://somesite.com/%7B7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D%7D.htm
2011-11-30 21:25:06.665 Craplet[48922:707] (null)
```

So, escaping seems to work

Here's how you can programmatically escape the url:

```
NSString *escapedUrlString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

EDIT:

In your comment below, you said your server won't accept encoded braces and was there any other alternatives.  First, I would try and get the server fixed.  If that's not possible ... I haven't tried this with braces etc... but the layer below NS networking classes is CFNetworking.

See this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH5-SW2

From that doc:

```
 CFStringRef url = CFSTR("http://www.apple.com");
 CFURLRef myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, NULL);
 CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("GET");

 ....
```

Once again, haven't tried it and I'm running out.  might try it later but if a layer isn't working your first options are to move down the stack.

Comment: Hey Bryan, thanks for your response!  Unfortunately, it appears that the server doesn't accept the percent escaped values for curly braces.  Is there a way to form a GET request with explicit curly braces in objective c?

Comment: I added a note about CFNetworking - one option is to keep moving down the stack.  But, if possible I would try and get the server fixed :)

Comment: Thanks for updating.  We found out that it was a small encoding error elsewhere that was tripping us up.  Issue resolved, but I'll be keeping this code around for future reference in case I run into other networking issues.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Need to create GET request without encoding curly brackets. Could you pls provide a code that generates request using CFNetwork? I tried that in the link its throwing an EXEC BAD access exception

Comment: I am trying to use @ to escape a string and I can't seem to do it. It ignores the @ at the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 8):

Bryan's answer is perfectly great (+1 to him!), but another solution would be to use NSString's [`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) method.

Like this:

```
NSString * originalURLAsString = [NSString stringWithString: @"http://somesite.com/{7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D}.htm"];
NSString * properlyEncodedString = [originalURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: properlyEncodedString];
```

I hope this info helps you out!

Comment: +1 - was editing mine as you appended with this answer - our saves crossed :)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for posting!  This trick didn't work for me because the other side is expecting explicit curly braces, not the percent escaped values.  Do you know of a way to form a GET request with explicit curly braces in objective c?

Comment: do you have control over the server you're talking to? Servers should always handle percent escaped URL's.

Comment: I don't have control over the server I'm talking to.  The curly braces are in a query string.

Answer (score 0):

To call using CFNetwork can use the follwoing

```
-(void)getDataFromUrl{
    CFStringRef tempURLA = CFSTR("http://my.test.server/iostest/index.html?{\"a\":\"b\"}");
    CFStringRef tempUrlSting = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)tempURLA,CFSTR("{}"), CFSTR("\""), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

    CFURLRef myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, tempUrlSting, NULL);

    CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("GET");
    CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, myURL,kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

    CFStringRef headerFieldName = CFSTR("Accept");
    CFStringRef headerFieldValue = CFSTR("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(myRequest, headerFieldName, headerFieldValue);


    [self performHTTPRequest:myRequest];

}

-(void)performHTTPRequest:(CFHTTPMessageRef)request {
    CFURLRef gotdatab = (__bridge CFURLRef)(CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopyRequestURL(request)));
//    NSLog(@"(CFHTTPMessageRef request  %@",gotdatab);

    CFReadStreamRef requestStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(NULL, request);

    CFReadStreamOpen(requestStream);

    NSMutableData *responseBytes = [NSMutableData data];
    NSError *error;

    while (TRUE) {

        if (CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(requestStream)) {
            UInt8 streambuffer[1024];
            int readBytes = CFReadStreamRead (requestStream,streambuffer,sizeof(streambuffer));
            NSLog(@"Read: %d",readBytes);
            [responseBytes appendBytes:streambuffer length:readBytes];
        }

        if (CFReadStreamGetStatus(requestStream) == kCFStreamStatusError) {

            error = (NSError*)CFBridgingRelease(CFReadStreamCopyError (requestStream));
            if ([error code] == 61) {
                // connection refused
                NSLog(@"Error occured: %d",[error code]);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (CFReadStreamGetStatus(requestStream) == kCFStreamStatusAtEnd) {
            NSLog(@"Stream reached end!");
            error = nil;
            break;
        }

    }//
    CFHTTPMessageRef response = (CFHTTPMessageRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(requestStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);

    if (response==NULL) {
        NSLog(@"response is null");
        return;
    }
}
```

The above was done using examples from [here](http://jameswilliams.me/developer/blog/2008/08/http-post-via-the-cfnetwork-stack/) and [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2013/May/msg00000.html)

But even the above method has the same issue. That is: if {} are not encoded the URL doesn't get generated. If the {} are encoded the server doesn't return a proper value.

Any other suggestions to resolve this posts issue?