# I can't load below url in UIWebview

Tags: uiwebview

Please verify why below url not loding in iOS App

https://opac.nie.edu.sg/uhtbin/cgisirsi.exe/x/MAIN/0/5?searchdata1=new%20title%202012%20mar%20ebooks{691}

Comment: Maybe showing how you are trying to load it might be a good idea in order to get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is the curly braces causing your issue: this post should help:
[NSURL with Curly Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335796/nsurl-with-curly-braces)