# NSMutableURLRequest truncating my URL

Tags: ios, rest, nsmutableurlrequest

My NSMutableURLRequest is truncating my URL when sending the request. Any thoughts why?

For Example:

```
url = @"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/authorizationheader?requiredauthhttpmethod=GET&requiredauthuri=https://mywebsite.com/restapi/accounts?user=myusername";
NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
[Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: Request returningResponse &resp error: &error];
```

But the server only receives:

```
https://mywebsite.com/restapi/authorizationheader?requiredauthhttpmethod=GET&requiredauthuri=https://mywebsite.com/restapi/accounts?user=
```

Why does "myusername" not get sent?

Comment: You have to URL-encode your parameters.

Comment: I tried this with no success. Any suggestions?

`authURLBase = @"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/authorizationheader?requiredauthhttpmethod=GET&requiredauthuri=";
    reqURL = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/accounts%@", [@"?user=myusername" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
url = [authURLBase stringByAppendString:reqURL];`

Comment: observe in your url once, there is httpmethod=Get and u r setting the request as post see it once

Comment: @sreekanthk that part is fine. My problem is with the NSMutableURLRequest truncating the username from the end of the entire request

Comment: try accounts/user?=myusername

Comment: @sreekanthk The format is specifically `/accounts?user=myusername` so I have to keep it in that order.

Comment: @AaronBrager You were right about the encoding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @erad No problem. You might want to look at using a networking library like AFNetworking, which will handle this kind of stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, you have to percent escape the reserved characters that you add as the `requiredauthuri` of your request. According to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), the characters that should be permitted unescaped are the alphanumeric characters, plus "-", ".", "_", and "~":

> 2.3.  Unreserved Characters
>
> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
> unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

See section 2 of the aforementioned [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more information.

Anyway, the proper percent encoding of the URL you are adding to your query is as follows:

```
NSString *reqURL = @"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/accounts?user=myusername";
NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
[allowedCharacters addCharactersInString:@"-._~"];
NSString *encodedReqURL = [reqURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowedCharacters];
```

You can then obviously use that `encodeReqURL` as normal:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/authorizationheader?requiredauthhttpmethod=GET&requiredauthuri=%@", encodedReqURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: By the way, the above requires iOS 7. If you need to support earlier iOS versions, you have to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547061/1271826, which applies the standard percent escaping, plus escaping those few reserved characters that otherwise wouldn't get escaped because, while they're allowed in a URL in general, they're confusingly not allowed in a parameter value within a URL.

Comment: This solution works too. Thanks a lot!
Do you happen to know why NSUTF8StringEncoding would not work in this case though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, because that's generally used in the context of translating `NSString` to `NSData` or vice versa, but is largely unrelated to the topic of percent-escaping. When you specify `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, you're specifying how to represent the string in `NSData`, but it does nothing with respect to reserved/unreserved URI characters.

Comment: OK so prior to any sort of encoding of the URL the server was receiving everything up to the last `=` sign. So, in general,NSURLConnection operates assuming my string was properly encoded, right? Then why do the first two `=` work without any problems and there is only a problem when I have two `?` signs? What does the role of `?` do in a NSURLConnection?

Comment: The `?` indicates that the "query" portion of the URL will follow. But to include the reserved `?` character _within_ the query portion of the URL will result in undefined behavior (and in your case, that strange behavior you apparently experienced). Personally, I wouldn't personally worry about why the server behaves like it does when you inappropriately include unescaped reserved characters in those query values, but instead simply make sure that they are properly percent-escaped before you add them to the URL. I suspect it's not a `NSURLConnection` issue, but rather a general HTTP behavior.

Comment: This is probably a ridiculous situation, but hypothetically if there were a scenario that there were two NESTED `?` Query Strings, how would you handle that? (i.e. /authorizationheader?requiredauthuri= .... /accounts?user= ... /members?user=username) Would you encode the first uri, then append it to the second uri, then encode this concatenated string, and finally append it to the authorization?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59118/discussion-between-rob-and-erad).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *userName = @"your username";
NSString *postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userName];
[request setHTTPBody:[postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: then what did u post in ur post method?

Comment: I added authKey and memberId in the HTTPHeaderField. These are the only two items I am allowed to add. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem did have to do with encoding. While I'm not 100% what caused the problem, I know that at some point between my NSMutableURLRequest and the server reception (likely due to something with how NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest works) the username was truncated. I suspect this is due to the fact that I have two Query Strings.

**The solution is to allow encoding with the "?" character.**

**Solution Code:**

```
authURLBase = @"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/authorizationheader?requiredauthhttpmethod=GET&requiredauthuri=";
reqURL = @"https://mywebsite.com/restapi/accounts?user=myusername";
authURL = [authURLBase stringByAppendingString:[reqURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?"]]];
```

Comment: This is the precise opposite of what I think you intended. This will percent escape everything _except_ the one character you were worried about, the `?`. lol. I assume to accidentally omitted the code to invert the set (either by calling `invert` on your mutable set, or create new set via `invertedSet`). For a more general solution, though, you should be percent escaping everything not in the RFC 3986 set of unreserved characters.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `invert` on the mutable set? I have never seen that method before.
I had tried using just a regular `[reqURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` but that did not work. My solution also happens to work for some reason.

Comment: If you wanted to percent escape only the `?`, rather than using `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?"]`, you'd use `[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?"] invertedSet]`. Or you could `NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?"]; [allowedCharacter invert];`, which is equivalent. But both of those would, if used with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`, handle the `?`, but has the unintended consequences of letting all of the other reserved character pass by unescaped.

Comment: OK so just to clarify, if I used my solution I first posted and there was some reserved character such as `#` or `%` in the URL, then those reserved characters would pass by unescaped and therefore I would theoretically run into problems during the NSURLConnection? 
(BTW I have used your solution in my real app. Works like a charm. Thanks again.)