# How to add request Parameters in NSMutableRequest

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I Have created a mutable request .

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// I want to add a request parameter - Not in the header or body.

   Add Your code here

//

[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Any one please help me

Comment: do you want to add your post parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU

```
NSString *post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data={\"user_id\":\"abc\",\"Method\":\"User_nji_abc\"}"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_BASE_URL];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                 NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){


        dicWholeValue=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


        NSLog(@"%@",dicWholeValue);

    }
    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
        NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded."); }
    else if (error != nil){
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            //Do any updates to your label here
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Could not connect to server." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

            [alert show];
            alert=nil;
            NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);

        }];

    } }];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you specified a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, so if that's what your server requires, you'd probably use `NSJSONSerialization` method `dataWithJSONObject` to build that `NSData` object that you'll specify with `setHTTPBody`. For example:

```
NSDictionary *params = @[@"search" : @"restaurants", 
                         @"postal" : @"10003"];     // supply whatever your web service requires

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(data, @"Unable to serialize JSON: %@", error);

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

But sometimes, a web service will return JSON, but will expect the request to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In such case, the format of the `NSData` is very different.

```
NSDictionary *params = @[@"search" : @"restaurants", 
                         @"postal" : @"10003"];     // supply whatever your web service requires

NSMutableArray *postArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [postArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [self percentEscapeString:obj]]];
}];
NSString *postString = [postArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Where you percent escape your string like so:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-._~/?"];
    return [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowedCharacters];
}
```

(Note, that requires iOS 7 or later. If supporting earlier iOS versions, you have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546848/url-encoding-ios-nsurl-error/24547061#24547061).)

Bottom line, we need more information about precisely what the web service API requires before we can advise you further.