# when request post jsondata requested URL show blank field only dictionary key are viewd

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [@"{\"id\":\"7\",\"user\":\"alok7@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"Ashok\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"price\":\"898989\",\"place\":\"disa\",\"time\":\"2014-10-22\",\"given_taken\":\"Given By\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dictionary];// jsonDict];

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);   

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[jsonRequest length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

output on requested link:

```
  {"id":"261","user":"","given_taken":"","name":"","gender":"","price":"0","place":"","time":""},{"id":"262","user":"","given_taken":"","name":"","gender":"","price":"0","place":"","time":""},{"id":"263","user":"","given_taken":"","name":"","gender":"","price":"0","place":"","time":""}],"success":1}
```

Comment: json directory.  {"employee_detail":[{"id":"263","user":"","given_taken":"","name":"","gender":"","price":"0","place":"","time":""}],"success":1}

Comment: It's unclear (a) what the functional purpose of the request is; (b) what was in the request; (c) what you expected in the response; and (d) what these two JSON snippets you shared with us are (are they responses? if so, why do they have different structure?). Clearly, you have to finish configuring request before you initiate it (see answer below), but you have other problems, please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: when i post on requested link my jsondata are not shown on server side. is there problem in dictionary structure.

Comment: i also checked isvalidjsonobject ..is true. then why i dont get data.

Comment: I don't know how `isvalidjsonobject` could have been true. Look at `jsonRequest`. It's not valid JSON. Look at your `jsonRequest` string, which you constructed by taking a fine JSON string, converted it to `NSData`, converted that to `NSDictionary`, and then passed that to `setHTTPBody` using `stringWithFormat` of the `NSDictionary` (which is not a JSON format). See my revised answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original question you created `NSMutableURLRequest`, you called `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest]` and then proceeded to try to finish configuring the request.

But, the `initWithRequest` will start the request, so make sure you finish configuring your request before instantiating the `NSURLConnection`.

Also, don't call `start` because the connection is automatically started for you. You only have to `start` if you created `NSURLConnection` with `startImmediately` of `NO`, which is not appropriate here.

---

In your revised question, you included code that says:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [@"{\"id\":\"7\",\"user\":\"alok7@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"Ashok\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"price\":\"898989\",\"place\":\"disa\",\"time\":\"2014-10-22\",\"given_taken\":\"Given By\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dictionary];
```

In that you're manually constructing the JSON string, converting that to a `NSData`, then converting that to `NSDictionary` (using `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option for some reason). You're then using `stringWithFormat`, to take that dictionary and convert it to a string (but not valid JSON) and sending that.

I'd suggest (a) don't create JSON strings manually, as that's fraught with simple typographical mistakes; (b) just create `NSDictionary` and then create `NSData` directly from that. For example:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = @{
    @"id" : @"7",
    @"user" : @"alok7@gmail.com",
    @"name" : @"Ashok",
    @"gender" : @"Male",
    @"price" : @"898989",
    @"place" : @"disa",
    @"time" : @"2014-10-22",
    @"given_taken": @"Given By"
    };

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(data, @"dataWithJSONObject failed: %@", error);

request.HTTPBody = data;
```

By the way, unrelated to your question, but you don't have to set `Content-Length` because `NSURLConnection` will do that for you.

Comment: hello rob...NSString *post = @"key1=val1&key2=val2";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
this is worked for me...data pass using string.

Comment: i want to use multiple textfield value enter by user at NSString *post string is it possible..?

Comment: If you're going to create a request like that (ie a request with a `Content-Type` of `x-www-form-urlencoded`), make sure to percent escape the values (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25281585/1271826). Percent escaping is not needed with JSON a requests, but is for `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests.