# Unity FB.API request returning unsupportedURL on iOS, working in editor

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Im requesting basic data from Unity app using official Facebook SDK.
The problem appears when I add first_name field into friends list

There is no issue in Unity Editor, problem only appears on **iOS**, console screaming **UnsuportedURL**

Issue does not appear without the **{first_name}** right after **friends**

Request:

```
me?fields=id,name,friends{first_name}
```

Unity Code:

```
FB.API("me?fields=id,name,email,friends{first_name},first_name", HttpMethod.GET, delegate(FBResult dataResult) {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataResult.Error)) {
            //error occured
            Debug.LogError(dataResult.Error);
            error(dataResult.Error);
            isFinished(true);

        } else {

            Debug.Log(dataResult.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this URL, using fields.

"me?fields=id,name,email,friends.fields(first_name),first_name"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like curly braces are the issue here breaking iOS NSURL

Escaping curly braces worked like here: 
[NSURL with Curly Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335796/nsurl-with-curly-braces)

```
"me?fields=id,name,email,friends%7Bfirst_name%7D,first_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following query:

```
"/me?fields=id,first_name,gender,picture,email,friends{id,first_name,gender,picture},invitable_friends{id,first_name,picture}"
```

... works fine in the Unity Editor but not on iOS. The previous solutions don't work.

Switching from curly brackets to regular brackets - Facebook rejects it for containing an invalid character.

Switching to escaped curly brackets (%7B and %7D) - Still returns Unsupported URL.

Here's how I fixed it in the end:

```
"me?fields=id,first_name,gender,picture,email,friends.fields(id,first_name,gender,picture),invitable_friends.fields(id,first_name,picture)"
```