# Url with curly braces gives unexpected nil

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the following code in my iOS Swift application:

```
let url = "http://api.example.com/"

func getShows(completion: ((json: JSON) -> Void)!, lastModified: String?) {
    var appendUrl = "shows?selector={\"general.active\":\"1\"}"

    appendUrl = self.url + appendUrl

    Alamofire.request(.GET, appendUrl, headers: headers)
        .responseData({ (result) -> Void inJes 
            if let res = result.result.value {
                let json = JSON(data: res)

                completion(json: json)
            }
        })
}
```

But it gives an error, saying `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

This is weird, because it works when the append url is `shows`, but as soon as I add the curly braces, it fails (`shows?selector={}` doesn't work either, so it's not the quotes)

I have already tried replacing the the curly braces with `%7B` and `%7D`, but this doesn't work either.

Any sensible comment on this would be appreciated :)

Comment: Shouldn't the JSON be part of the body instead of the url?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos There's no body for a GET request, so no. This actually works with the url without the braces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURL with Curly Braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335796/nsurl-with-curly-braces)